# Javascript and / or chrome extention : Remember folder path

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, path, directory

I was wondering if there is a way to remember a folder path in javascript.

Explanation : 
I have an application where the user have to select a folder to play songs that are in this folder. 
I would like this app to remember this path to play the songs the next time the user open the app.

As I understand it is not possible to do it with javascript, but is there a way to do it in a chrome extention ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 local-storage or webstorage to store some data. Details here:

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: The selected folder could contain thousands of songs. I'm not sure I can store all theses songs in Local Storage. Plus, the user can add / remove songs at any time.

Comment: But you can store the folder path in local-storage and retrieve it when user again visit your site.